# div in html does not get executed by browser

Tags: php, html, webserver

I'm making a website and on the profile page, I have a problem with some code there. There is also php used in the page but I don't think that's the problem here.
When I load my page on the browser and it is uploaded to my webserver, it does not show the `div` with the id 'personalinfo', when I look at it with "element inspect", that `div` does not exist for the browser. I can't find anything wrong in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minegeekz.com</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="profileStyleSheet.css">
    <style>
       title{
           background: url('<?php $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>') no-repeat;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="title">
        <div><h1><?php include 'profileheader.php' ?> </h1></div>
   </div>
   <div id="mid">
        <div class="leftsite">
            <div id="menu">
               <div style="border-top: 0px;">
                    Welcome, <?php include 'welcome.php' ?>
               </div>
               <div>
                   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
               </div>
               <div>
                <?php include 'loginout.php' ?>
            </div>
            <?php include 'registerlink.php' ?>
            <div>
                <a href="About.html">About</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <?php include 'forumlink.php' ?>
            <?php include 'profilelink.php' ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="profilehead">
            <div id="picture">
                <?php include 'avatar.php' ?>
            </div>
            ***<div id="personalinfo">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?><br>
                <?php echo $_SESSION['lname']; ?>
            </div>***
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightsite">
    </div >
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyrighted 2015</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`<?php session_start(); ?>` goes first. You're outputting before header.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: The html seems correct. There may be a problem with your php code.

Comment: "division"? that's a mathematics term. I think you meant "div". and who knows if your session arrays are even set.

Comment: they are set because when I display that session in the title area, it does work. That's not the problem.

Comment: html is correct, problem is the content within this div is nothing due to any error in Session, just write something else , sure you will find it in browser.

Comment: you're outputting before header and you're not made aware of it; I said so already. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: That gives no errors and when I set this `<p>hello</p>` between the the div, the paragraph does not show up either.

Comment: view your HTML source and it might be related to your stylesheet. that file is `.php` extension, right?

Comment: No it was .html but I changed it and linked it to that file and it stayed the same.

Comment: `.html` extension does not parse PHP, unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Not much else here I can do to help, good luck.

Comment: thank you I will search further then.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have declared the url in wrong way check the below code

`.title{background: url("<?php $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>") no-repeat;}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I had to change `echo $_SESSION['fname'];` to `echo $_SESSION[fname];` then it works fine. I don't understand why, but it works